# Hibernate NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello Friends : I get the error above the second time i try to save to DB the same ticket and cop instances to DB, Here is my code pojo class Cop and DaoCop and main method. The ticket and its Dao class are the same structure with the cop class. The idea is that a cop can create many tickets and one ticket can only be created by one cop. Therefore when i try to associate the same cop that already exist in our DB to many tickets i get and a hibernate error of NonUniqueException.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cop")
@NamedQueries(
    {
       @NamedQuery
       (
               name = "findPolicierByMatricule",
               query = "from Policier pol where pol.numMatricule = 
               :matricule"

       )
    }
 )
public class Cop
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
          "policier_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="policier_generator", sequenceName = 
         "policier_seq", allocationSize=1)
  @Column(name = "idCop")
  private int idCop;

  @Column(name="numMatricule")
  private int numMatricule;

  @Column(name="prenom")
  private String prenom;

  @Column(name="nom")
  private String nom;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cop", cascade =
     {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, 
      CascadeType.DETACH})
  private List<Ticket> listTickets;

  .....
}

  public class DaoCop
  {
    @Override
    public Policier findById(Object matricule)
    {
          openCurrentSessionwithTransaction(); //Get the session and 
                Begin transaction
          Query query = 
          getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("findPolicierByMatricule");
          query.setParameter("matricule", matricule);
          Cop cop;
          List<Cop> list = (List<Cop>) query.getResultList();
          if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
          {
               cop = null;

           }
         else
         {
            cop = list.get(0);
         }
         closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction(); //Commit and Close the 
           //session
        return cop;
   }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    daoTicket = DaoFactory.getDaoTicket();
    daoCop = DaoFactory.getDaoCop();
    Cop cop;
    Ticket ticket;
    Cop temp = (Cop) daoCop.findById(numMatricule);
    if(temp == null) //If the cop with the nummatricule does not exist          
    {
      cop = new Cop(numMatricule, prenom, nom);//in our DB we create an 
                  //new one
    }
    else
    {
      cop = temp; //else we use the one arleary exit.
    }
    ticket = new Ticket("21-21-18",51.02);
    //Link Objects in Memeroy

    cop.add(ticket);

   //Save Objects in DB
   daoTicket.create(ticket);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new id for the cloned object. Can you try this for the else part:

```
else
{
  Cop copCopy = temp.createCopyWithNoId()
  DaoCop.add(copCopy)
  cop = copCopy; //else we use the one arleary exit.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate! But how should i create a copy with no Id ?

Comment: The id is a primary key in your database, so it shouldn't have a duplicate id. Even though you want a copy, it should have a new id, which will be automatically generated.

Comment: BTW the method findById on DaoCop class does not use a primary key to load the data from the database, it uses a unique id(not primary) that is stored in the table. All primary Keys are auto-generated.

Comment: So, even with unique ids, you cannot have two copies with the same id, right? That's why you get the error. You either remove the unique constraint or have the copy with a different id.

Comment: I removed the unique constraint on all my tables in database but still same error. Excuse-me i don't understand which two copies of the same id are you talking about ?

Comment: Oh, that's weird. I mean this `cop = temp; //else we use the one already exit.`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the CascadeType in Cop Class so i removed it completely and the error went away.